# How to create (or at least, describe) horizontal progress bar with thresholds?

Tags: javascript, css, charts, progress-bar

I'm looking to create a horizontal chart with thresholds at certain percentages- if you've ever used Battle.Net, kind of similar to their download bar:

[Blizzard Download Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIPLZ.png)

I'm sure there's a name for it, I just don't know what it is...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this just in case it helps. Have 'fun'.
You can edit the little threshold pointer so they look stylish with css. But yea that all depends on what you want to do

```js
// Btw, I'm a big fan of the canvas element that's why I'm doing this. Otherwise, you can also use a progress bar
var c = document.getElementById('progressBar'),
  dt = document.getElementById('download-text'),
    btn = document.querySelector('button'),
    p2 = document.querySelector('progress');

var cx = c.getContext('2d');
var counter = 0,
  loop;

btn.onclick = function() {
  btn.innerText = 'N';
  var timeInter = setInterval(function(){
      btn.innerText += 'o';
    },70);
  setTimeout(function(){
    clearTimeout(timeInter);
    btn.hidden = true;
    p2.hidden = false;
    progress2();
  },1000);
}

var loop2 = '',
    counter2 = 0;
function progress2() {
  counter2++;
  var percentage = (counter2 / 17).toFixed(2);
  if (percentage - 0 >= 100) {
    percentage = 100;
  }
  
  p2.value = percentage - 0 +'';
  if (percentage - 0 > 100) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(loop2);
  } else {
    loop2 = requestAnimationFrame(progress);
  }
  //This is me failing to animate the progress bar
}

function progress() {
  counter++;
  var percentage = (counter / 17).toFixed(2);
  if (percentage >= 100) {
    percentage = 100+'.00';
  }
  dt.innerText = "Download: " + percentage + "%";
  
  cx.fillStyle = '#00FFFF';
  cx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width * percentage / 100, c.height);
  cx.strokeStyle = '#ccc';
  cx.beginPath();
  cx.moveTo(100, 70);
  cx.lineTo(100, 0);
  cx.stroke();

  cx.moveTo(300, 70);
  cx.lineTo(300, 0);
  cx.stroke();
  if (percentage - 0 > 100) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(loop);
  } else {
    loop = requestAnimationFrame(progress);
  }
}
progress();
```

```css
#progressBar {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  z-index: -10;
}
#progressBar,
#download-text,
#playable,
#optimal,
button,
progress{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
button,
progress{
  top:200px;
}
#download-text {
  height: 70px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: transparent;
}
#playable,
#optimal {
  width: 100px;
  height: 43px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
#playable {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 72px;
  left: 100px;
}
#optimal {
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 72px;
  left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="progressBar" width="430px" height="70px"></canvas>
  <div id="download-text">Hello</div>
</div>
<div id="playable">PLAYABLE</div>
<div id="optimal">OPTIMAL</div>

<button type="button">Please don't press me just stick to canvas</button>

<progress max="100" hidden="true"></progress>
```